# Разница в производительности при вычислении среднего значения

Tags: python, массивы, математика, производительность, python-3.8

Столкнулся с интересной ситуацией. Написал код, чтобы проверить, так ли это.

Нам надо посчитать среднее арифметическое некоторых значений. Условие в том, что мы не знаем, сколько значений у нас будет в итоге. И прикол в том, что добавлять числа в массив и считать сумму массива после быстрее, чем считать сумму сразу, без добавления в массив.

```
import time
t0 = time.time()
for j in range(100000):
    sm = 0
    cn = 0
    for i in range(150):
        cn += 1
        sm += i * (i + 1)
    l = sm / cn
print('%.6f' % (time.time() - t0))
t0 = time.time()
for j in range(100000):
    a = []
    for i in range(150):
        a.append(i * (i + 1))
    l = sum(a) / len(a)
print('%.6f' % (time.time() - t0))
```

Вывод такой:

> 2.146408 - с суммой

> 1.838875 - с массивом

Вопрос, а почему второе быстрее?

Comment: дело в том что sum - функция с реализацией на C.  Все встроенные функции быстрее

Answer (score 2):

Если для вас важна скорость выполнение - воспользуйтесь [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html):

```
import numpy as np  #  pip install numpy

def orig1(N):
    sm = 0
    cn = 0
    for i in range(N):
        cn += 1
        sm += i * (i + 1)
    return sm / cn

def orig2(N):
    a = []
    for i in range(N):
        a.append(i * (i + 1))
    return sum(a) / len(a)

def np1(N):
    return np.mean(np.arange(N) * np.arange(1, N+1))
```

сначала проверим правильность вычислений:

```
In [302]: orig1(150)
Out[302]: 7499.666666666667

In [303]: orig2(150)
Out[303]: 7499.666666666667

In [304]: np1(150)
Out[304]: 7499.666666666667
```

теперь скорость:

```
In [305]: %timeit orig1(150)
13.5 µs ± 71.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [306]: %timeit orig2(150)
13.3 µs ± 68.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [307]: %timeit np1(150)
7.72 µs ± 109 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Numpy покажет себя во всей красе для более крупных массивов - возьмем 1500 элементов вместо 150:

```
In [308]: %timeit orig1(1500)
177 µs ± 2.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [309]: %timeit orig2(1500)
153 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [310]: %timeit np1(1500)
10.7 µs ± 147 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

тут уже разница не в разы, а на порядки)

Comment: Это, конечно, супер. Но это в данном случае я знаю, какие данные там будут. А если я их, например, таскаю каждый раз с сервера, чтобы потом посчитать? Мне было интересно почему, казалось бы, более медленный код работает быстрее. Если мне надо посчитать среднее  арифметическое чисел 0, 1, 2, 6... то я просто напишу return (i * (i + 2) - 1) / 3; Явно короче и быстрее варианта с numpy?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в первом случае на одно действие больше: ещё есть `cn += 1`. На это тоже тратится время.

Comment: ок, а то, что сумма должна работать за O(n), а то, что добавлять в массив - это не O(1), не смущает? По факту операций должно быть больше во втором случае, тк нам надо переаллоцировать массив. а если и не надо, то всё равно цикл O(N), сумма O(N) и того и там, и там O(2N)

Comment: Думаю, `sum` по сравнению с итерационным `+=` вносит больше. Но, тут только мерить..

Comment: @СашаНовожилов list.append как раз О(1), так что не смущает [ссылка](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: @СашаНовожилов А зачем переаллоцировать массив? Это ж не С, где все элементы массива должны лежать в последовательных адресах памяти. Здесь внутреннее представление списка вполне может быть списком в каноническом понимании, т.е. элементы могут иметь иметь указатели на следующий (и возможно предыдущий) элемент списка, а сам список иметь указатель на последний элемент. Тогда добавление в список - вполне себе О(1).

Comment: @Эникейщик 
These operations rely on the "Amortized" part of "Amortized Worst Case". Individual actions may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container. - так что это неправда про O(1). А про то, что это связный список - неправда. Каким образом тогда обеспечить доступ к каждому за O(1)? Да и выделение памяти работает явно дольше, чем cn += 1

Comment: Память увеличивается по геометрической прогрессии. Т.е. будет логарифм перевыделений от числа элементов

Comment: @СашаНовожилов если то, что пишет официальный сайт, вам "неправда", то пусть будет неправда. Уберите из первого способа cn += 1 и сравните.

Comment: `+= 1` в питоне реально медленно работает, и да, это дополнительная операция в цикле, дело именно в этом

Comment: @CrazyElf, это касается и `sm += i * (i + 1)` ;) Функция `sum()` написана на C и работает быстрее

Answer (score 1):

Проверяем тезис о лишней операции cn += 1 в первом опыте:

```
import time
t0 = time.time()
for j in range(100000):
    sm = 0
    cn = 0
    for i in range(150):
        cn += 1
        sm += i * (i + 1)
    l = sm / cn
print('%.6f' % (time.time() - t0))
t0 = time.time()
for j in range(100000):
    sm = 0
    cn = 0
    for i in range(150):
        sm += i * (i + 1)
    l = sm / (i+1)
print('%.6f' % (time.time() - t0))
t0 = time.time()
for j in range(100000):
    a = []
    for i in range(150):
        a.append(i * (i + 1))
    l = sum(a) / len(a)
print('%.6f' % (time.time() - t0))
```

Результаты соответственно:

2.877234

**2.094582**

2.381735

Т.е. убрали ненужную операцию, и скорость сразу стала лучше чем в вашем втором примере.

Comment: Читайте, пожалуйста описание. Там сказано, что непонятно откуда придут данные и в каком объеме, это нам и надо вычислить. Мне код остался от другого программиста, и тк переписывать очень много (а, с учетом того, что надо на плюсы), то вообще может уйти месяц, а надо сделать чтобы работало "здесь и сейчас", приходиться даже такое оптимайзить, чтобы создать пространство для переноса на плюсы.

Comment: @Саша Новожилов Не понимаю, вы же сами писали "Мне было интересно почему, казалось бы, более медленный код работает быстрее." Я вам показал, почему. Потому что в коде есть одна лишняя операция, которая существенно замедляет выполнение. Это ответ на ваш вопрос. Убераете ее и медленный код НЕ работает быстрее. А если этот код написал кто-то, то видать он не понимал, как надо такие вещи писать. Только и всего.   Если ваши данные будут  "откуда-то приходить" -   ну вот цикл обработки и должен не содержать этой операции. Вы же эту обработку будете сами писать. Надеюсь теперь понимаете "как надо".